# Looking for Taylor series expansion of $\ln(x)$

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion

We know that the expansion of $$\sin(x)
$$ is $$x/1!-x^3/3!\cdots$$

Without using Wolfram alpha, please help me find the expansion of $\ln(x)$.

I have my way of doing it, but am checking myself with this program because I am unsure of my method.

Comment: Expansion about what?  There is none about $0$, but we can find one about any $a\gt 0$. The most popular choice is $a=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas cr*p! Yeah I meant a=1

Comment: Then integrate the expansion of $\frac1{1+u}$ about $u=0$.

Comment: See [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series).

Comment: @AndréNicolas the reason we cannot do expansion about a= 0 , i know its not defined left side but still a>0 there is so it should give the graph isnt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=\ln(x).$$

The Taylor expansion around $a$ is
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n,$$

so for $a = 1$,

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x},\; f''(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2},\; f^{(3)}(x) = \frac{2}{x^3},\ldots,\; f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{x^n}.$$

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(x-1)^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(x-1)^n$$

$$\ln(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(x-1)^n$$

The more popular formula is obtained when we substitute $x$ with $1+x$

$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}x^n$$
or
$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^n$$
This is for $|x|<1$.

Comment: $|x| \leq 1, x \neq 1$. It's important that this series *does* hold at $x = 1$, since that gives us the alternating harmonic series.